# How to match the column based on 2 conditions (1st based on unique field and 2nd based on date range) in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose this is my 1 `dataframe` with `userId`, `deviceID` and `Clean_date` (date of log in)

**df =**

| userId | deviceID | Clean_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 202030 | 28-Jul-22 |
| XYZ123 | 304050 | 27-Jul-22 |
| ABC123 | 405032 | 28-Jul-22 |
| PQR123 | 385625 | 22-Jun-22 |
| PQR123 | 465728 | 22-Jun-22 |
| XYZ123 | 935452 | 22-Mar-22 |

Suppose following is my `dataframe` 2 with `userId`, `deviceID` and `transferdate` (date of device transferred to userid)

**df2 =**

| userId | deviceID | transferdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 202030 | 20-May-22 |
| XYZ123 | 304050 | 03-May-22 |
| ABC123 | 405032 | 02-Feb-22 |
| PQR123 | 385625 | 21-Jun-22 |
| PQR123 | 465728 | 2-Jul-22 |
| XYZ123 | 935452 | 26-Apr-22 |

Now, I want to identify 3 scenarios and create new column with identifier

1. P1 = User logging in with multiple devices on same day for df 1 and if one of the both devices are **not** belonging the same user.
2. P2 = User logging in with multiple devices on different day for df 1 and if one of the both devices are **not** belonging the same user.
3. NA = User logging in with multiple devices on same day/different day for df 1 and if both devices are belonging the same user.

Hence my output table should look like:

**df3 =**

| userId | deviceID | Clean_date | transferdate | identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 202030 | 28-Jul-22 | 20-May-22 | NA |
| XYZ123 | 304050 | 27-Jul-22 | 03-May-22 | P2 |
| ABC123 | 405032 | 28-Jul-22 | 02-Feb-22 | NA |
| PQR123 | 385625 | 22-Jun-22 | 21-Jun-22 | P1 |
| PQR123 | 465728 | 22-Jun-22 | 02-Jul-22 | P1 |
| XYZ123 | 935452 | 22-Mar-22 | 26-Apr-22 | P2 |

**I have tried below code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f, Window

w=Window.partitionBy("userId") 
w2 = Window.partitionBy("userId", "Clean_date") 
df3 = (
    df
    .withColumn(
        "Priority",
        f.when(f.size(f.collect_set("deviceID").over(w2)) > 1, "P1")
        .when(f.size(f.collect_set("deviceID").over(w)) > 1, "P2")
        .otherwise("NA")
    )
)
```

However, I am unable to incorporate `transferdate` from df2 in this code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to join with `df2` before you can reference its columns. So, the first operation should be: `df.join(df2, on='userId').withColumn(...`

Comment: will the user always have same device_id across both the tables (like in your example)?

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframes are unique at the 3 columns and the users in both tables will have same devices, the below solution seems to work.

```
data1_sdf.join(data2_sdf, ['userid', 'deviceid'], 'left'). \
    withColumn('num_dev_sameday_gt1', 
               (func.count('deviceid').over(wd.partitionBy('userid', 'clean_dt')) > 1).cast('int')
               ). \
    withColumn('num_dev_diffday_gt1', 
               (func.size(func.collect_set('clean_dt').over(wd.partitionBy('userid'))) > 1).cast('int')
               ). \
    withColumn('sameday_atleast_1dev_notuser', 
               func.max(((func.col('num_dev_sameday_gt1') == 1) & (func.col('clean_dt') < func.col('transfer_dt'))).cast('int')).
               over(wd.partitionBy('userid'))
               ). \
    withColumn('diffday_atleast_1dev_notuser', 
               func.max(((func.col('num_dev_diffday_gt1') == 1) & (func.col('clean_dt') < func.col('transfer_dt'))).cast('int')).
               over(wd.partitionBy('userid'))
               ). \
    withColumn('identifier',
               func.when((func.col('num_dev_sameday_gt1') == 1) & (func.col('sameday_atleast_1dev_notuser') == 1), func.lit('P1')).
               when((func.col('num_dev_diffday_gt1') == 1) & (func.col('diffday_atleast_1dev_notuser') == 1), func.lit('P2')).
               otherwise(func.lit('NA'))
               ). \
    show()

# +------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
# |userid|deviceid|  clean_dt|transfer_dt|num_dev_sameday_gt1|num_dev_diffday_gt1|sameday_atleast_1dev_notuser|diffday_atleast_1dev_notuser|identifier|
# +------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
# |PQR123|  385625|2022-06-22| 2022-06-21|                  1|                  0|                           1|                           0|        P1|
# |PQR123|  465728|2022-06-22| 2022-07-02|                  1|                  0|                           1|                           0|        P1|
# |XYZ123|  304050|2022-07-27| 2022-05-03|                  0|                  1|                           0|                           1|        P2|
# |XYZ123|  935452|2022-03-22| 2022-04-26|                  0|                  1|                           0|                           1|        P2|
# |ABC123|  202030|2022-07-28| 2022-05-20|                  1|                  0|                           0|                           0|        NA|
# |ABC123|  405032|2022-07-28| 2022-02-02|                  1|                  0|                           0|                           0|        NA|
# +------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+
```